# Installation problem in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Does SQL Server 2005 Express have a problem with installing on single user systems?

Comment: Can you add more info to your setup, the problem you see etc? The simple answer is "no" but that won't help you...

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server 2005 will install just fine on a single user system. A better question is why you would want to. Most of the time when I've seen people want to do this, they're using it as a simple data store for a desktop application they are building. If that's what you're doing, you should probably choose an *in-process* database like Sqlite, Sql Server Compact Edition, or even MS Access instead. Of course there are exceptions, but really if this is part of an app that must coexist with other apps on a machine that will serve as some user's primary desktop, you should really avoid trying to push a whole server at them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing some sort of problem then look at the `Microsoft documentation` for [How to: Install SQL Server Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143722%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to step by step approach and the compatibilities related information.

There are few links that will go through the detailed step by step approach of SQL Server install. Check these:
[install_sql_server_2005_2008_as_database_server](http://www.bopup.com/support/install_sql_server_2005_2008_as_database_server.html)
[Installing SQL Server 2005 Express Edition: step-by-step guide](http://www.sswug.org/articles/viewarticle.aspx?id=21350)

If you still facing problem in installation then specify the exact error that you are facing..

Hope this help..